# Cannot select an image from a flowlistview, in order to navigate to another view so as to see and/or update some details of this image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have used commands to follow the MVVM pattern and everything works, but I cannot choose the photo and navigate to my UpdatePhotoPage, having the photo as parameter. The best I managed was to have a simple navigation to the UpdatePhotoPage through the PhotoPage.cs(since I prefer through PhotoViewModel) by tapping an image but without seeing the details of the photo. My code:

```
public PhotosPageViewModel()
    {
        Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
        NewPhotoCommand = new Command(OnNewPhotoCommand);
        LoadCommand = new Command(OnLoadCommand);
        PhotoSelectedCommand = new Command<Photo>(OnPhotoSelectedCommand);
    }
    private void OnPhotoSelectedCommand(Photo photo)
    {
        App.NavigationService.NavigateTo(PageNames.UpdatePhotoPage, photo);
    }
```

And my XAML:

```
 <controls:FlowListView x:Name="PhotoFlowListView"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        FlowColumnCount="3" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"                           
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                        RowHeight="160"
                        FlowItemsSource="{Binding Photos}"
                        SelectionMode="Single">
        <controls:FlowListView.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped"
                                  Command="{Binding PhotoSelectedCommand}"                                                                                                  
                                  EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource LocalItemTappedConverter}">
            </behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior>
        </controls:FlowListView.Behaviors>

        <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>                
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="3">
                    <ImageButton
                        Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PhotoStyle}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    </ImageButton>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
    </controls:FlowListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add **GestureRecognizers** on the **StackLayout** and pass the pass the whole model (Photo) as parameter to Command. In this way you don't need to use the `FlowListView.Behaviors` any more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xxx.xxxPage"
             x:Name="View" // set the name of ContentPage
             
             >
```

```
 <StackLayout Padding="3">
        <ImageButton
                       x:Name="image"
                        Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PhotoStyle}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </ImageButton>

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference View},Path=BindingContext.PhotoSelectedCommand }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />  // pass the whole model (Photo)

        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

</StackLayout>
```